# минимально-необходимые файлы для работы компонента (на старом ядре) Bitrix

Tags: битрикс

Опыта в разработке на Битрикс практически нет, поэтому спрашиваю здесь, какие файлы минимально необходимы для работы компонента на Битрикс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Минимально необходимые файлы в старом ядре Битрикс это только component.php (собственно, код компонента) и .description.php (это служебная информация о компоненте). Все остальное необязательно: .parameters.php (параметры компонента), папка lang (языковые файлы), папка templates (шаблоны), папка images (картинки для компонента).
При этом, в файле .description.php название компонента желательно задавать через языковые файлы (особенно, если компонент создается для использования более чем на одном сайте), поэтому файл /lang/ru/.description.php можно отнести к категории условно-необходимых.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятен вопрос, зачем это?
Если нужно что-то быстро загрузить через ajax, где в php есть ваш компонент, то достаточно в php добавить вчего 1 строку:

```
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
```

Далее подключать ваш компонент.
Если же нужно в дополнение к компоненту какой-то модуль, то кроме той строке о которой я написал выше, можно дописать, например

```
CModule::IncludeModule("iblock"); или CModule::IncludeModule("sale");
```

Comment: Это мне в тестовом задании вопрос такой дали, а я сам не могу однозначно дать ответ